# MVC 3 updating page using a datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, submit

I have a problem and after 2 hours of try & error & google I Came here to ask.

Im pretty new to Web development and new with Ajax.

I have a simple page with a jquery ui's datepicker and a div with render an action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="datepicker"></div>    
}

<h2>Lista de trabajos</h2>

<div id="trabajos">
    @Html.Action("List", "Trabajo", new { dia = Model.Fecha })
</div>
```

So far so good. I want to click on a Date on the datapicker (its configured through an script) and call this action again with another date on the @model.

The problem is that if I use this:

```
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $("form").submit();
            }
```

It post perfectly when I click on a date, but if i use:

```
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $("form").submit(function (e) { });
            }
```

It doesn't post anymore.

As novice, Im trying to accomplish it step by step. Im trying to just post (without ajax by now) and send the new date to my controller, so:

How I send data (I think that dateText is what I want to send) to my action (Who is expecting an string). When I accomplish that I'll go to Ajax but if I can't send the date to the action and make a refresh to get a new model...

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
$("form").submit();
```

triggers the submit event immediately and POSTs to the server.

The following code:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) { 

});
```

simply redefines the `submit` handler but doesn't submit immediately. You need to click on the submit button and then the anonymous function will be invoked (which is empty and would eventually perform a normal submit but you need to click on the submit button). So if you wanted to use AJAX:

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
    var form = $(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            // the form was successfully sent to the server using an AJAX call
            // do something with the result
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Jesus Rodriguez, you can send it like this: `data: { date: dateText }` and in your controller action use the same parameter name `public ActionResult Foo(DateTime date)` and it will be populated with the date that was selected.

Comment: Thank you, I saw that and deleted my comment :P

Answer (score 0):

The second form is adding a handler for the submit event, not submitting the form. If you want to post the form using ajax, you should use the [post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post) method.

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var $form = $('form');
            $.post( $form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
               // do something with the result of the post request
            });
          }
```